# Show formatted HTML Content to Microsoft Bot User

Tags: botframework

Is it possible to show formatted HTML Content inside a Bot Card/Attachment?
In this Case, we retrieve the content field of a Dynamics 365 CRM Knowledge Article which is in HTML Format and want to show it to the bot user.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried ?

Comment: On which channel do you want to show your html and which SDK are you using, .NET or node.js?

Comment: Have you checked my answer? Any update?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the channels in the Bot Framework don't support HTML rendering. You may refer to this issue: [Can a .html file be rendered in cards](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/issues/212) and [HTML should be sanitized in messages](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/604).

[image]

One alternative way is that to extract information from your html and create cards to show them, to create cards in Bot Framework, please refer to the official [Rich Cards Bot Sample for .NET SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/cards-RichCards) / [Rich Cards Bot Sample for node.js SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/cards-RichCards).

Another approach is that we use markdown to make a hyperlink to your html.

For example, in C#, you can simply code like this:

```cs
var text = @"[Google Search](http://www.google.com)";
await context.PostAsync(text);
```

But markdown is not supported by all channels too, you may refer to this [Bot Framework markdown support by channel](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jamiedalton/2016/08/22/bot-framework-markdown-support-by-channel/) for more information.