# Customizing Adaptive Card appearance using RenderedAdaptiveCards inside bot framework SDK

Tags: botframework, html-rendering, adaptive-cards

I am developing a Bot using Microsoft Bot Framework. I am using Adaptive Cards for displaying flights to users but they have a lot of limitations on their appearance. I am trying to render the adaptive card from one of the dialogs within my bot framework by creating a adaptive card renderer using my own hostconfig.json and then attaching the Html of my adaptive card back to the chat window. But its not working :(

```
    public static Attachment CreateFlight(Flight flight)
    {
        var renderedAdaptiveCard = AdaptiveCardRenderer
            .RenderCard(new AdaptiveCard
            {
                Body = new List<AdaptiveElement>
                {
                    new AdaptiveContainer {Items = CreateFlightAdaptiveElements(flight)}
                },
                Actions = new List<AdaptiveAction>
                {
                    new AdaptiveShowCardAction
                    {
                        Card = new AdaptiveCard
                        {
                            Body = new List<AdaptiveElement>
                            {   

                            },
                            Actions = new List<AdaptiveAction>
                            {
                                new AdaptiveSubmitAction
                                {
                                    Title = "Select",
                                    Data = flight.Segments.Select(x => $"{x.Airline} {x.FlightNo}")
                                        .Aggregate((i, j) => i + "/" + j),

                                }
                            },
                            BackgroundImage = new Uri($"{DomainUrl}/Images/ac_background.jpg")
                        },
                        Title = "Select"
                    },

                },
                BackgroundImage = new Uri($"{DomainUrl}/Images/ECEFF1.png")
            });

        var attachment = new Attachment
        {   
            ContentType = "application/html",
            Content = renderedAdaptiveCard.Html
        };

        return attachment;
    }
```

Am I trying something that is impossible here ? How to change the default grey looks of my bot ? My primary channels would be Skype, Slack etc so I don't have plans to integrate this to a Web Chat. Kindly help me with this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea behind [Adaptive Cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/) is to allow each channel to render the cards in a way that's specific to that channel. A card "adapts" to any environment that might support it. While Adaptive Cards offer a lot of flexibility, the bot can only do so much because it's ultimately the channel that's in charge of rendering the card.

> Card Authors describe their content as a simple JSON object. That
>   content can then be rendered natively inside a Host Application,
>   automatically adapting to the look and feel of the Host.
>
> For example, Contoso Bot can author an Adaptive Card through the Bot
>   Framework, and when delivered to Skype, it will look and feel like a
>   Skype card. When that same payload is sent to Microsoft Teams, it will
>   look and feel like Microsoft Teams. As more host apps start to support
>   Adaptive Cards, that same payload will automatically light up inside
>   these applications, yet still feel entirely native to the app.
>
> Users win because everything feels familiar. Host apps win because
>   they control the user experience. And Card Authors win because their
>   content gets broader reach without any additional work.

As you probably know, the [RenderedAdaptiveCard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/sdk/rendering-cards/uwp/render-a-card) type is meant to be used in client-side code. That means it can help you if you want to make your own channel for example, but it's not really meant to be used in a bot. Your code isn't working because there is no HTML attachment type and most channels don't support HTML at all. You can find more information in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47750012/show-formatted-html-content-to-microsoft-bot-user) and [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/issues/212).

Hopefully you can achieve the appearance you're looking for using the tools available to you, such as images and links.